# What does advance up to $500 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, money

Text:

> For this project, you will buy between $5 - $1,000 USD (no minimum) worth of goods (which you will actually get to keep!) and submit your receipts for reimbursement.
>   This means that you will need to advance up to $500 on a personal credit or debit card while you participate in this project. Are you able to do this?*

I don't want to get ripped off that's why I am asking if this means that here I am actually expected to buy at products at least for $500?

Comment: Someone wants a $500 advance from you. This really looks like a scam. I personally wouldn't do it.

Comment: An "advance" here, means paying money before receiving anything.  They're expecting you to spend at least $500 of your own money and then wait for them to pay you back later.  Yeah, it's very scammy.

Comment: Thank you! I indicated that I was not willing to do that. I don't expect them to hire me that way but I don't care:) Thank you again guys!

Comment: 'Advance' implies (in this case) to pay for something before you receive it. Let the buyer beware. I think this includes 'Don't be an advancer.'

Comment: There is a well known 'employment' scam involving spending your own money for variously-described things, such as office set-up, office equipment, starting inventory, etc, which things, needless to say, never arrive.

Comment: Quite apart from this being an obvious scam, there is some confusion in the quoted text as to what the minimum amount is (first we are given the $5-$1000 span, which implies that the minimum is $5, and then told that there is no minimum) and what the maximum is (the $5-$1000 span implies that the maximum is $1000, but then we are told that the advance is supposed to be up to $500). It is anybody's guess whether this is a result of the incompetence of those who drafted the text, or of their deliberately trying to disorient their victims still more.

Comment: @jsw29 - many people laugh at 'incompetent scammers', not realising that the material is designed to filter out the non-gullible.